# matlab and octave operator precedence of mldivide: a*A\b gives (a*A)^-1*b instead of a*inv(A)*b

Tags: matlab, octave, operator-precedence, inverse

Using Octave, with 
`d*FT\N` gives `(d*FT)^-1*N` instead of the expected `d*(FT\N)`

For a demo see http://tpcg.io/1En0tS

Is this the same in Matlab? 
If no, should I file a bug report?

Comment: It may not have been what you intended, but your expectations are controlled by knowing the correct formula.  If you saw that code for the first time, you might have a different expectation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Octave behavior appears to match [the Matlab documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/operator-precedence.html):

> Within each precedence level, operators have equal precedence and are evaluated from left to right.

The multiplication and division operators are all in a single precedence level:

> Multiplication (`.*`), right division (`./`), left division (`.\`), matrix multiplication (`*`), matrix right division (`/`), matrix left division (`\`)

Comment: Thank you. In fact, I consider this decision an unfortunate legacy: Typically I'd replace any `A^-1` with A\. Better replace it with `(A\..)`.